# Validation nested models in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, hibernate-validator

I have a problem with validation of nested models, look:

```
class A{
   @NotNull
   Integer i;
   B b;
}
class B{
   @NotNull
   Integer j;
}
```

In spring controller:
`@Valid @RequestBody...`

It properly validate `i`, but not validate `j`.   How to force Spring to validate arbitraly deep ?

And second thing:
Is it possible to do following validation:   Object of class 'A' is proper only and only if exactly one of `i` an `j` is `null`.

```
class A{
   Integer i;
   Integer j;
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Object graph validation is supported and you have to annotate `B b` with `@Valid` like below.

```
class A{
  @NotNull
  Integer i;
  @Valid
  B b;
}
```

Please refer https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.3#section-object-graph-validation for more details.

For second part of you question, you can create a custom Validator class. You would also need a custom annotation for that Validator. You can check the details at documentation page [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.3#validator-customconstraints). A sample for custom Validator is [here](http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/).

Comment: What if B is a collection that contains the items to be validated? Will it also work?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 it's an old answer, but yes, it will work.

Comment: I can confirm that it works.