# How to apply "hasErrors" for nested java object in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, validation, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

My view in thymeleaf for the "max" field does not work. How do I change it so that everything works correctly? The filter entity is used as the object. Thank you in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<h1>Filter</h1>

<br>
<br>

<form th:method="Post" th:action="@{/icarus3310/satellites-library/filter }" th:object="${filter}">

    <label for="name">Enter name: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{datasetName}" id="name"/>


    <br><br>

    <label for="max">Enter max: </label>
    <input type="number" th:field="*{sceneFilter.cloudCoverFilter.max}" id="max"/>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('max')}" th:errors="*{max}"></div>



    <br><br>

    <label for="min">Enter min: </label>
    <input type="number" th:field="*{sceneFilter.cloudCoverFilter.min}" id="min"/>

    <br><br>

    <label for="end">Enter end: </label>
    <input type="date" th:field="*{sceneFilter.acquisitionFilter.end}" id="end"/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="start">Enter start: </label>
    <input type="date" th:field="*{sceneFilter.acquisitionFilter.start}" id="start"/>

    <br><br>

    <label for="lowerLeft.x">Enter x: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{sceneFilter.spatialFilter.lowerLeft.x}" id="lowerLeft.x"/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="lowerLeft.y">Enter y: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{sceneFilter.spatialFilter.lowerLeft.y}" id="lowerLeft.y"/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="upperRight.x">Enter x: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{sceneFilter.spatialFilter.upperRight.x}" id="upperRight.x"/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="upperRight.y">Enter y: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{sceneFilter.spatialFilter.upperRight.y}" id="upperRight.y"/>
    <br><br>



    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">


</form>

<br>
<br>



</body>
</html>
```

This my entity Filter

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "maxResults", "datasetName","sceneFilter" })
public class Filter {
final Integer maxResults = 50000;

private String datasetName;
private SceneFilter sceneFilter;


public Filter() {
    if (this.sceneFilter == null) this.setSceneFilter(new SceneFilter());
}
```

}

This SceneFilter

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "spatialFilter","cloudCoverFilter", "acquisitionFilter" })
public class SceneFilter {
private SpatialFilter spatialFilter;
private CloudCoverFilter cloudCoverFilter;
private AcquisitionFilter acquisitionFilter;

public SceneFilter() {
    if (this.spatialFilter == null) this.setSpatialFilter(new SpatialFilter());
    if (this.cloudCoverFilter == null) this.setCloudCoverFilter(new CloudCoverFilter());
    if (this.acquisitionFilter == null) this.setAcquisitionFilter(new AcquisitionFilter());
}
```

}

This СloudCoverFilter (here is the max field for which I want to do validation)

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "max", "min","includeUnknown" })
public class CloudCoverFilter {


@Size(min = 2)
private Integer max;
private Integer min;
final Boolean includeUnknown = true;
}
```

If necessary, I can provide a controller. But everything works correctly there. The problem is the nesting of objects, validation works without problems with ordinary objects

Comment: Do you add `@Valid` on the nested object? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005850/validation-nested-models-in-spring-boot

Comment: Yes, I have added validation in the controller. Everything is as it should be. I am 100 percent sure that there is a problem with the thymeleaf syntax here

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).