# Unable to validate nested object in a json using Spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javax-validation

I've a spring boot project which contains a controller that receives a json payload.
The json payload looks like this:

```
{
  "name":"Andrew",
  "age":28,
  "location":{
   "country":"US",
   "city":"New York"

  }
}
```

and corresponding pojo class

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private Location location;

  // Getters and Setters
}

public class Location {
  private String country;
  private String city;

  @JsonCreator
  public Location (@NotNull String country,@NotNull String city){
    this.country = country;  
    this.city = city;
  }

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

My requirement is if the location is present in the above json payload, then the country and city should be validated for a null check.
If the location is not passed in the payload, then neither country , nor city should be validated.
Is there a way to do this validation using Spring annotation? The current annotation @NotNull isn't seem to be working.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "not working"?  Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: What will you do with `NullPointerException` if this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Put `@Valid` or `@Validated` on both classes `Persion` and `Location` to active validation.

Also dont forget add `@Valid` to dto in controller. Refer to this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005850/validation-nested-models-in-spring-boot)